# static variable: not defined inside other constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-internals

i have trouble accessing a static member of a class. the simplest example of my use-case is:

```
class A:
    _tmpl = '<{}>'
    print(_tmpl)
    VAR = tuple(_tmpl.format(var) for var in ('a', 'b'))
```

this prints `<{}>` as it should from the `print` statement; but the line with the `tuple` raises the exception:

```
NameError: name '_tmpl' is not defined
```

what is happening here? how can i fix it (`A._tmpl` will not work either...).

Comment: use `A._tmpl` instead of `_tmpl`.

Comment: nope; `A` is not yet (fully) defined. that does not work: `AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute '_tmpl'` (should have added that to the question...)

Comment: The workaround is to simply do it after the class declaration: `A.VAR = tuple(... A._tmpl ...)`

Comment: @deceze thanks for the workaround! could you explain what i am missing? why can i access `_tmpl` in the `print` statement but not inside `tuple`? ...ok, the dupe explains it all. thanks!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes, I realized that later.

Comment: This is a consequence of the way that class block scope works, it is a special case, that doesn't create an enclosing scope, however, that means that comprehension constructs, which essentially use a function scope, cannot access variables in the class block's namespace, the same way a method couldn't access `_tmpl ` without `A. _tmpl`, *but inside the class body `A` doesn't exist yet*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks a lot! and thanks for the duplicate. great answer there!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist make sure to check out both, both answers have a lot of good info

Comment: Also, relevant section in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

Comment: After watching discussion, I found a solution: `VAR = tuple(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.get("_tmpl").format(var) for var in ('a', 'b'))`. It is not pythonical but works.

Comment: @Sraw yeah, sometimes you should just use a for-loop...